# How to add breakpoints to fill in the rest of the function name via gdb tab completion?

Tags: c++, gdb

I want to add a breakpoint at the function name (e.g. `foo::step`) to debug how this function is executed. This function (`foo::step`) is a member of a linked library which has been built with debug symbol. Every time I set a breakpoint with `b foo::step`, I had to type the entire function name, which is cumbersome for complex function names. I have tried to autocomplete the function name via tab completion, but this is not working. I don't know if this is because this function is derived from a linked library.

I’d like to fill in the rest of the function name when setting breakpoints at function name, and this function is derived from a linked library.

Comment: Try setting the breakpoint after executing `start` gdb command.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI Thanks for your comment. I have tried your advice and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @n. m. could be an AI,

> Try setting the breakpoint after executing `start` gdb command.

`tab completion` will work after the `start` command is executed.